# Join two dataframes before exporting as .csv files

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I am working on a large questionnaire - and I produce summary frequency tables for different questions (e.g. df1 and df2).

```
a<-c(1:5)
b<-c(4,3,2,1,1)
Percent<-c(40,30,20,10,10) 
df1<-data.frame(a,b,Percent)
c<-c(1,1,5,2,1)
Percent<-c(10,10,50,20,10)
df2<-data.frame(a,c,Percent)
rm(a,b,c,Percent)
```

I normally export the dataframes as csv files using the following command:

```
write.csv(df1 ,file="df2.csv")
```

However, as my questionnaire has many questions and therefore dataframes, I was wondering if there is a way in R to combine different dataframes (say with a line separating them), and export these to a csv (and then ultimately open them in Excel)?  When I open Excel, I therefore will have just one file with all my question dataframes in, one below the other.  This one csv file would be so much easier than having individual files which I have to open in turn to view the results.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you open a file connection, you can write to it with write.csv and cat using the append parameter available in both functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your end goal is an Excel spreadsheet, I'd look into some of the tools available in R for directly writing an xls file. Personally, I use the **XLConnect** package, but there is also **xlsx** and also several `write.xls` functions floating around in various packages.

I happen to like **XLConnect** because it allows for some handy vectorization in situations just like this:

```
require(XLConnect)

#Put your data frames in a single list
# I added two more copies for illustration
dfs <- list(df1,df2,df1,df2)

#Create the xls file and a sheet
# Note that XLConnect doesn't seem to do tilde expansion!
wb <- loadWorkbook("/Users/jorane/Desktop/so.xls",create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb,"Survey")

#Starting row for each data frame
# Note the +1 to get a gap between each
n <- length(dfs)
rows <- cumsum(c(1,sapply(dfs[1:(n-1)],nrow) + 1))

#Write the file
writeWorksheet(wb,dfs,"Survey",startRow = rows,startCol = 1,header = FALSE)
#If you don't call saveWorkbook, nothing will happen
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

I specified `header = FALSE` since otherwise it will write the column header for each data frame. But adding a single row at the top in the xls file at the end isn't much additional work.

Comment: That's amazing @joran - what a great package! Just a few quick additional questions... Firstly, is it possible to have the name of the dataframe just above the table (which would make life a lot easier matching the individual dataframe to the interview question). The names of my dataframes will refer to each question - i.e. age, gender etc. so this will be very useful.  Also, for visual purposes, is it possible to put a border around the dataframes?

Comment: @KatieT Yes, adding borders in possible. See `?createCellStyle`, `?setBorder`. It won't be terribly convenient to do that programmatically, though, since you'll have to specify the correct borders on each perimeter cell individually. The easiest way to add the df name would be with a separate column, like `c('Age',NA,NA,...)`.

Comment: Could you explain the way in which the separation between the data.frames when exported to excel works. It works fine in this example but when trying the same code with more varied data.frames it can cause the data.frames to overlap. I have tried changing the numbers within ‘rows <- cumsum(c(1,sapply(dfs,nrow)[-1] + 1))’ but have not found a reliable method of ensuring a consistent space between data.frames.

Comment: @KatieT That's simply my mistake. My slight edit should fix it. That bit should simply be taking the cumulative sum of 1, #rows of 1st data frame + 1, #rows of 2nd data frame + 1, etc. up to the second to last data frame. Which should be the row that each data frame should begin at. If you wanted a two row gap, you'd add 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

As James commented, you could use

```
merge(df1, df2, by="a")
```

but that would combine the data horizontally. If you want to combine them vertically you could use `rbind`:

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3,...)
```

(Note: the column names need to match for `rbind` to work).