# R: Constructing a table from three dataframes of equal columns but different names

Tags: r

I have three dataframes of variable row length:

```
df1 (column names a,b,c)

df2 (column names d,e,f)

df3 (column names g,h,i)
```

How can I combine them into one table 
(one dataframe under the other)

```
table.all <- rbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

only works for same column names but my column names are different.

Then save this table to a csv:

```
write.csv(table.all ,"table.all .csv")
```

Comment: Two possibilities: Change the column names to make them matching. Or, maybe a more sensible approach, reshape the data.frames to long format before rbinding them. That way you could retain the information in the column names.

Comment: Thanks Joran: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230949/join-two-dataframes-before-exporting-as-csv-files

Comment: Thanks Roland. I will reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure all columns are the same data type, otherwise you will get an error, but if your data frames are of the same structure, then the solution could be

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1,b="a",c=3)
df2 <- data.frame(d=2,e="a",f=3)
df3 <- data.frame(g=3,h="a",i=3)
library(plyr)
ll <- list(df1,df2,df3)
ldply(ll, function(l){ names(l) <- c("col1","col2","col3") 
                       l})
```

And this will work with data frames with different number of rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll have to decide at some point what the column names should be for your final `data.frame`.  Why not set all the column names to what you want them to be then `rbind`?